# django import module with a system name

Tags: django, import

I would like to import a function from the views.py file of my **import** module.
The following code does not work: `from import.views import myFunction`. How to do?

**

### **Edit:**

** So far I was able to import other files from the import module:

```
sys.path.append(settings.SITE_ROOT+'import')
import myFile as test
```

It doesn't seem to work for the view though, don't know why!

Comment: **import** is python keyword. we cant use import as module name

Comment: I have edited my post: it works for some files...